# How to use UNIX terminal input redirection in C?

Tags: c, unix, input, terminal, redirect

I have this C program that gets the input from the user and sends it to a method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "constants.h"
#include "lines.h"
#include "compare.h"

//gets arguments and sends to compare.c
int main() {
   int op = 1;
   char filename[20];

   scanf("%d ", &op);
   gets(filename);
   if ((char) op + '0' < 49 || (char) op + '0' > 57) {
       printf("Error: Invalid input");
       exit(0);
   }
   readstdin(filename, op);
   return 0;
}
```

but instead of executing the program and reading from stdin, I want it to read from the unix terminal so that:

```
./sort [field] < input_file
```

will read into the file. ([field] is option if no input is put in, default is 1).

For example the command to execute the C program in UNIX would look like this:

```
./sort 1 < test.txt
```

How do I go about doing this?

Any help is much appreicated
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to pass the filename alone or the complete data from command line?

Comment: both filename and field from the command line but I want the filename and field as separate values

Comment: Then just use command line arguments. Use argc & argv in main()

Comment: AusCBloke's definitely matches the description of what you wanted to actually accomplish.  If you use redirection like you originally supposed then the contents of that file are piped to the program.  I've had assignments where the professor wanted an interactive program but gave us a file with space delimited input so we could use redirection like that and from the perspective of the program there is no difference from a user typing in the contents of the file manually.  Not pertinent to this situation but might be good to know its possible.

Comment: thank you very much matt for the input

Comment: @Matt i didnt understand what you meant until now, I have just realized I am screwed. Is there anyway i can extract the file name from "./sort 1 < test.txt"

Comment: No, you can't pass a file name using redirection.  Instead you use command line arguments as explained in the answer below.  Redirection takes the data in the file which is not what you were actually looking for. Sorry, I was trying to give some extra info it confuse you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, you're getting your arguments the wrong way in your code. If what you're wanting is to run your program such as `./sort <option> <filename>`, then you don't use `stdin` to retrieve these arguments.

The arguments in a C program are passed to main using the following function signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`argc` is the number of command line arguments passed to the program, and `argv` is the array of strings of those arguments.

With a run of `./sort 5 test.in`:

- `argc` will equal 3
- `argv[0]` will be `"./sort"`
- `argv[1]` will be `"5"`
- `argv[2]` will be `"test.in"`

You should check that the value of `argc` is 3 to ensure that 2 arguments have been passed (`"5"`, `"test.in"`), as well as the filename (`"./sort"`) for a total of 3.

If you want to have optional fields, it would be better to have them after the compulsory ones, or better yet is to use something like [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Getopt.html) where you could instead have something like: `./sort --file test.in` or `./sort --opt 5 --file test.in`. It's probably unnecessary for this case, but it's an option.

You can parse the integer option using `atoi` or `strtol`, however you like, to convert it from a string (`char*`) to an integral type and `fopen`, `fgets`, `fclose` to read from the input file.